# R to trim the space

Tags: cobol, zos

When I passing empty input I have to get no space in delimiter || like this. but I am gitting 1 length space | |. how to remove this space in COBOL.

- ALPHANUMERIC MOVE, RECEIPT-NO

  ```
       IF WSCLMLO-RECEIPT-NO EQUAL SPACE OR LOW-VALUES      
           MOVE CZ-1                  TO  WS-S1             

       ELSE                                                 
           SET VALID-DATA-NOT-FND     TO  TRUE              
           MOVE SPACES                TO  WS-FIELD-TEXT-DATA
           MOVE ZEROES                TO  WS-FIELD-LENGTH   
           MOVE CZ-13                 TO  WS-FIELD-LENGTH   
           MOVE WSCLMLO-RECEIPT-NO    TO  WS-FIELD-TEXT-DATA

           PERFORM X20-CALC-TEXT-DATA-LENGTH                

           MOVE WS-DATA-POS           TO  WS-S1             
           MOVE WS-DATA-LENGTH        TO  WS-E1             
       END-IF                                               

       MOVE WMATRANI-BSB-NO           TO WSCLMLO-BSB-NUMBER 

       MOVE WMATRANI-ACCOUNT-NO       TO WSCLMLO-ACCOUNT-NO
  ```

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without seeing your `WORKING-STORAGE SECTION`.  What data item holds your delimiters?  Is it `CZ-1`?

Comment: Yes It CZ-1 value